# Android Studio 3.1.2 can't delete file opened by itself

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed brandnew Android Studio and haven't to mess with the configuation. It happened when I try to clean Kotlin project, I didn't even touch the code or the config manually.

Kotlin is configed by running Configure Kotlin in project and I press clean project. It fail to delete a file and it has to be deleted manually after closing Android Studio.

Later it failed to create debug directory 'C:\Users\myname\AndroidStudioProjects\thesimpleplainbasic\app\build\intermediates\res\debug'

Comment: try deleting build folder

Comment: @Redman Sorry if I replied too late, I will try tomorrow

Comment: It's useless, the android studio is using it so I close Android Studio and delete it. It seems Android Studio needs permission from itself.